# Login on a site using urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to get information from this site http://cheese.formice.com/maps/@5865339 , but when i request using urllib.urlopen, its says that i need to login, i was using this code:

```
import urllib
data = {
        'login':'Cfmaccount',
        'password':'tfmdev321',
        'submit':'Login',
    }
url = 'http://cheese.formice.com/login'
data = urllib.urlencode(data)
response = urllib.urlopen(url, data)
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not using `urllib` directly, but you may find it easier working with the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) package. `requests` has a `session` object [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994044/using-python-requests-library-to-login-to-website)

```
import requests

url = 'http://cheese.formice.com/forum/login/login'
login_data = dict(login='Cfmaccount', password='tfmdev321')
session = requests.session()

r = session.post(url, data=login_data)
```

That will log you in to the site. You can verify with:

```
print r.text #prints the <html> response.
```

Once logged in, you can call the specific url you want.

```
r2 = session.get('http://cheese.formice.com/maps/@5865339')
print r2.content #prints the raw html you can now parse and scrape
```

Comment: But im still getting "You must log in to view the map database" :|

Comment: I changed the answer to use request session objects, and referenced another answer along similar lines. It seems as though you will need a session.

Comment: How do you do it using ONLY urllib?

Comment: Does this deal with CSRF tokens?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this with only the standard library using a custom opener with a cookie processor. An example is provided below.

```
# Login to website using just Python 3 Standard Library
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import http.cookiejar

def scraper_login():
    ####### change variables here, like URL, action URL, user, pass
    # your base URL here, will be used for headers and such, with and without https://
    base_url = 'www.example.com'
    https_base_url = 'https://' + base_url

    # here goes URL that's found inside form action='.....'
    #   adjust as needed, can be all kinds of weird stuff
    authentication_url = https_base_url + '/login'

    # username and password for login
    username = 'yourusername'
    password = 'SoMePassw0rd!'

    # we will use this string to confirm a login at end
    check_string = 'Logout'

    ####### rest of the script is logic
    # but you will need to tweak couple things maybe regarding "token" logic
    #   (can be _token or token or _token_ or secret ... etc)

    # big thing! you need a referer for most pages! and correct headers are the key
    headers={"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 Chrome/81.0.4044.92",    # Chrome 80+ as per web search
    "Host":base_url,
    "Origin":https_base_url,
    "Referer":https_base_url}

    # initiate the cookie jar (using : http.cookiejar and urllib.request)
    cookie_jar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

    # first a simple request, just to get login page and parse out the token
    #       (using : urllib.request)
    request = urllib.request.Request(https_base_url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    contents = response.read()

    # parse the page, we look for token eg. on my page it was something like this:
    #    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="random1234567890qwertzstring">
    #       this can probably be done better with regex and similar
    #       but I'm newb, so bear with me
    html = contents.decode("utf-8")
    # text just before start and just after end of your token string
    mark_start = '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'
    mark_end = '">'
    # index of those two points
    start_index = html.find(mark_start) + len(mark_start)
    end_index = html.find(mark_end, start_index)
    # and text between them is our token, store it for second step of actual login
    token = html[start_index:end_index]

    # here we craft our payload, it's all the form fields, including HIDDEN fields!
    #   that includes token we scraped earler, as that's usually in hidden fields
    #   make sure left side is from "name" attributes of the form,
    #       and right side is what you want to post as "value"
    #   and for hidden fields make sure you replicate the expected answer,
    #       eg. "token" or "yes I agree" checkboxes and such
    payload = {
        '_token':token,
    #    'name':'value',    # make sure this is the format of all additional fields !
        'login':username,
        'password':password
    }

    # now we prepare all we need for login
    #   data - with our payload (user/pass/token) urlencoded and encoded as bytes
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
    binary_data = data.encode('UTF-8')
    # and put the URL + encoded data + correct headers into our POST request
    #   btw, despite what I thought it is automatically treated as POST
    #   I guess because of byte encoded data field you don't need to say it like this:
    #       urllib.request.Request(authentication_url, binary_data, headers, method='POST')
    request = urllib.request.Request(authentication_url, binary_data, headers)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    contents = response.read()

    # just for kicks, we confirm some element in the page that's secure behind the login
    #   we use a particular string we know only occurs after login,
    #   like "logout" or "welcome" or "member", etc. I found "Logout" is pretty safe so far
    contents = contents.decode("utf-8")
    index = contents.find(check_string)
    # if we find it
    if index != -1:
        print(f"We found '{check_string}' at index position : {index}")
    else:
        print(f"String '{check_string}' was not found! Maybe we did not login ?!")

scraper_login()
```

[Link to this script on GitHub](https://github.com/luxzg/Python3/commit/68b780e3ab1402be9e37a8a3f6d06bcea4b6732a#diff-0680ac0627f7a09dfac8ce2d1eed06be)

Comment: I've found Github gist (gist.github.com) to seem better for examples like this than a full repository. It's built for sharing small snippets or a few files.

Comment: Thanks @QuinnMortimer , will keep it in mind for next time!

Comment: I got a question today on GitHub about this, so quick recap here. Question was about use of "token" as well as username/password fields. These need to match actual login form of website you are trying to login to. Use something like Chrome inspect tool to dig into the form, check names of interactive fields like username and password (can be non-english, or variations like login/user/pass/pwd etc), and check if it holds any hidden fields like token. If not, token can be skipped. But also 4th or more fields can exist, so you need to modify to match real login page.