# How to pass Auth in a "get" request using urllib.request Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, get, httprequest

To make a get request with Python I was using `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` but I am having problem passing username and password to http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/ali/pass

[image]

```
import urllib.request
data={"user": "ali","passwd":"pass"}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(data)
data = data.encode('utf-8')

url = "http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/ali/pass"
response = urllib.request.Request(url,data=data)

print(urllib.request.urlopen(response))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Login on a site using urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048168/login-on-a-site-using-urllib)

Comment: No it did not help. Actually I am having problem with auth. I just have to make a basic auth request. I am tring that dummy website. as i am learning.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using requests module which work perfectly but I am trying to learn about urllib.request module so that is why.

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
r=requests.get('http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/ali/pass', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('ali', 'pass'))
print(r.status_code)
```